# Show/hide effect for all list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build image gallery with folders. When user press on folder name it hides all the pictures and shows only pictures for this folder. I have managed to do it but when images are hiding or showing they change move to one column and then animate. How can I make them to stay in-line all the time?

```
$('#folderList li').click(function () {
    var folderToShow = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#galleryList li').hide("slide", {}, 1000);
    $('#galleryList li.' + folderToShow).show("slide", {}, 1000).css("display", "inline-block");
});
```

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9sL2/)

Comment: In CSS add `float:left` to your list element will change the way it animates. Give that a try.

Comment: wow, is working, I didn't expect to be that simple:)

Comment: Added it as an answer, so you can close it .. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a float property in your CSS

```
#galleryList ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    float:left
}
```